# how to upgrade from win 8 single language (retail bought) to win 8 pro with volume licence key (used in a company)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I cannot downgrade nor upgrade. I get an error message when I insert the VLK I get an error, “This key won’t work. Check it and try again, or try a different key”.

What other option do I have? Who would my VLK provider be?  Would it be the person sitting in our HO working for Microsoft dept??

Comment: Sounds like your trying to pirate Windows.  You cannot upgrade from a retail Single Language license to a VLK Professional license.  Your VLK provider is your company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with Windows 8 without performing a full reinstall. If you look at the [valid upgrade paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx), you will see that the only way that you can cross from single-seat licensing to VLK licensing is with a physical Windows 8.1 Pro Preview (Volume License) disk (downloaded version will not work).

I would not recommend that, because there is no guarantee that you can upgrade from Windows 8.1 Preview to Windows 8.1, which would require you to reinstall the entire OS.

Comment: Thx Ramhound. Was only looking for confirmation. Not trying to pirate windows. The scenario is that the client received a new desktop with win8 single language from a contractor as a replacement. I was requested to configure this pc only to find out that the pc has win8 SL on. I only have a VLK and is not able to upgrade nor downgrade this machine except if I get a retail key for win8 pro. So once I get that key will I be able to upgrade to win8 pro with VLK? Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you Darth Android for your comments.  Your link was helpful.

Comment: @user252675 No, that is incorrect. If it only has a Single-License edition of Windows 8 on it, it cannot effectively be switched to VLK without formatting and reinstalling the OS. Upgrading to Pro first will not help the situation.

Comment: Thank you for all the imput. I eventually replaced the drive loaded win8pro with the vlk and voila!! This site is helpful :)

Comment: @user252675 Awesome! If this answer helped you, then it's usually customary to click the outline of a checkmark to mark the answer as "accepted".